# OptaPlanner the timetabling example does not run on JDK 11

Tags: optaplanner

[OptaPlanner Uncaught exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a095B.png)

Answer (score 0):

This a bug with (Open)JDK 11 that is fixed in the upcoming 7.14.0.Final.

Workaround for older versions: use (Open)JDK 8.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the bug is with the version OptaPlanner-distribution- 7.13.0 Final. Do I have to wait for the OptaPlanner- 7.14.0 Final version?

Comment: Yes, or use JDK 8.